# Maven import creating duplicate classes in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Since I'm relatively new to maven, I followed a quick tutorial to set up maven and install it to create a custom plugin in IntelliJ. I followed the tutorial outlined [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/maven-repo-for-craftbukkit.109166/). After running BuildTools.jar and running `$ mvn install`, I tried creating a new project.

However, every time I reference a class in `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3`, it brings up two options: one with the reference `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3` and another duplicate in `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.v1_8_R3`. I doubt this is supposed to happen since when I add it as a regular dependency in IntelliJ, the duplicates disappear and all the net minecraft classes share `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3`.

[image: PacketPlayOutPosition shares net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3 and net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.v1_8_R3]

Another weird thing I've found is how certain classes, for instance CraftPlayer, will only show up once with the path `net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.v1_8_R3` which might possibly indicate that this isn't a duplicate folder...?

How would I fix this? I've tried google searching but nothing relevant seems to come up. Would running `$mvn install` again do anything?

Comment: ID adds dependencies according to your Maven configuration. What do you have in `dependencies` section in pom.xml?

Comment: You can navigate into each of duplicated classes (Navigate | Class action) and check from which jar does it come from and try to understand from which dependency this jar is added.

Comment: @Andrey I have the dependency for Spigot. `<groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>`, `<artifactId>spigot</artifactId>`, `<version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`, and `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: They both come from the same jar. For some reason, there's a v1_8_R3 folder inside the net/minecraft/server/v1_8_R3 folder. Also, some objects only have one reference. For instance, CraftPlayer only has net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.v1_8_R3

Comment: best would be to post your `pom.xml` file here, we can't help without knowing how your classpath looks like

Comment: it may have a connection with plugins that exists in your pom.xml.
Taking the case of mapstruct for example, it generates classes in the generated-source directory, when we call a mapper, the generate class is injected.
it is very likely that this is a similar case, share with us your pom as well as the external libraries to have more visibility

Answer (score 0):

run mvn:dependency tree and resolve the jar conflicts